# Proper way to set timeout on a method in Java

Tags: java

I've looked over some existing answers here on SO and I've used [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) in combination with [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to set timeout with [TimeUnit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) to method.

But I'm trying to set timeout on a method inside my service implementation meaning that caller class is consuming interface.

So I'd like to avoid implementing callable in my service implementation, because I want this method to get executed in the same Thread.

Is there other way to set timeout or simulate timeout on a given method ?

Comment: What do you mean by "timeout"?  If you mean kill the operation after some period of time, you can't do that without running the operation in a separate thread.  (You can, of course, embed timer checks in loops in the code, and, eg, throw an exception when the time limit is exceeded, but this requires significant "cooperation" on the part of the "suspect" code.)

Comment: hi Hot Licks that is exactly what I meant, sorry for poor problem description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at [`TimeLimiter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/TimeLimiter.html) from [guava](/questions/tagged/guava) that can take any class and produce time-limited proxy. But it still uses thread pool internally to wait for `Future` (at least the default [`SimpleTimeLimiter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/SimpleTimeLimiter.html) implementation).

I you want to run method in the same thread, you must have another thread to interrupt it after given timeout. And interruption won't always work. Thus thread pool and `Future` is the only way.

Comment: hi Tomasz Nurkiewicz I'm not sure why I said that I don't want it to run in the separate thread. I said this because this code is already executing as part of the runnable object in several threads and I meant not to add more complexity. But as long as it "looks" like same thread it's good enough for me, because I'm creating sequential process (which is run by many threads at the same time).